# Setter For PreferredContentSizeCategory

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a setter for this `UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory`, as I need to make a slider inside the app to detect the font size the user preferred.
First I thought of making a scale value & multiply it with the font size when user select value from the slider, but I found that we can change the font size from settings
so is there a way to set `UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory` to a specific value programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. An individual third-party app (like yours) cannot change the user's preferred content size category. That is a global user setting; the only way it gets changed is for the user to set it (e.g. in Settings, or in the Control Center).